# ASP.NET MVC4 List of all areas

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application in which I am creating multiple areas, is there a way I can find out programmatically the number of areas that are present and their names.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` registers each area route with the `DataTokens["area"]` where the value is the name of the area.

So you can get the registered area names from the `RouteTable`

```
var areaNames = RouteTable.Routes.OfType<Route>()
    .Where(d => d.DataTokens != null && d.DataTokens.ContainsKey("area"))
    .Select(r => r.DataTokens["area"]).ToArray();
```

If you are looking for the `AreaRegistration` themselves you can use reflection to get types which derives from `AreaRegistration` in your assambly.

Answer (score 0):

`AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` cannot be used pre-initialization of the web application. However, if you want to get the areas without calling `RegisterAllAreas()`, e.g. in an automated test, then the following code may be helpful:

```
     var areaNames = new List<string>();
     foreach (var type in typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AreaRegistration)))) {
        var areaRegistration = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as AreaRegistration;
        areaNames.Add(areaRegistration.AreaName);
     }
```

Note that `MvcApplication` is the class derived from `HttpApplication`. You can use any class name as long as that class is in the same assembly as the assembly registrations, i.e. the classes derived from `AreaRegistration`. If you have split up your application with areas in more than one assembly, then you'd need to adapt this code accordingly so it searches all those assemblies.